# Visual studio Code : Connot compile module unless the --module flag is provided

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am getting an error with TypeScript code file and it seems like an common error but i am unable to fix that. I am new to Visual Studio Code.

```
Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using tsconfig.json or you do it in default way?

Comment: yes i am using tsconfig.json

Answer (score 1):

So, I understood your problem - it is really common exception and to solve it you should analyse [compiler options](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler-Options)

So, if you compile your code over `tasks.json` you can define several addition arguments for compiler like this

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",

    // The command is tsc. Assumes that tsc has been installed using npm install -g typescript
    "command": "tsc",

    // The command is a shell script
    "isShellCommand": true,

    // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
    "showOutput": "silent",

    // args is the HelloWorld program to compile.
    "args": ["-m", "commonjs", "HelloWorld.ts"],

    // use the standard tsc problem matcher to find compile problems
    // in the output.
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

so `-m` means `--module` compiler command.

## Edited

So, if you use tsconfig.json, you can find default configuration with module settings [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json#examples)

`"module": "commonjs"`:

- `module` - flag that tell compiler use module system
- `commonjs` - module system

I hope it can solve your problem! Good luck!

Comment: Putting that setting in tsconfig.json is a better approach, then it will work with other build systems as well.

Comment: Note: After adding the tsconfig.json, the changes to intellisense took effect only after restarting Visual Code.